# docker-compose mysql Access denied for user symfony@'172.18.0.1'

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, mariadb, symfony4

I have a DB issue while running a `Symfony4` project.

> docker-compose.yml

```
db:
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DATABASE_NAME}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'yes'
      MYSQL_USER: ${DATABASE_USERNAME}
    image: 'mariadb/server:10.4'
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    volumes:
      - 'db-data:/var/lib/mysql'
```

> .env

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://symfony:symfony@db.localhost/symfony
###< doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
DB_HOST=db.localhost
DB_NAME=symfony
DB_USERNAME=symfony
DB_PASSWORD=symfony
DATABASE_PORT=3306
DATABASE_HOST=db.localhost
DATABASE_USERNAME=symfony
DATABASE_PASSWORD=symfony
DATABASE_NAME=symfony
DATABASE_PORT=3306
PROJECT_NAME=oversight-api
```

I got an error `Access denied for user symfony@172.18.0.1`
I am not sure what the `172.18.0.1`. Should I add `db.localhost` to `/etc/hosts`?

How to solve this issue?

Comment: When you spin up a docker it creates it's own network, 172.18.0.0 is the network it created for the docker layer.   it allows you to ping docker-container2 when you sit on docker-container1 without knowing the IP address. I think the obvious question would be, did you create the user symfony within the MySQL container and give it permission to the database?

Comment: @user1628449 I didn't do anything includes adding `symfony` user. I just executed `docker-compose up -d`

Comment: @user1628449 that is not true. The container is configured through the environment variables. In particular, the user created through the environment variables is a superuser. I was able to spin-up the container locally with the exact configuration given.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mac you can resolve the database url by `host.docker.internal`.
On other OS you can name your container with `container_name: my_db` in docker_compose.yaml and use `my_db` as host

Comment: I am using Ubuntu

Comment: try naming the container in that case, it should resolve the IP by itself

Answer (score 0):

Instead of connecting to `172.18.0.1`, we can connect to `localhost`. We forwarded the container-port `3306` to the local machine port `3306`, thus the port is accessible through `localhost`.

---

If the docker-host is a remote machine, and we want to connect to the container running on the remote machine, we need to connect to the remote machine's network address or DNS name (that is the name/the address on the physical network, not the docker-internal network. In essence, the address we would use to ssh into the machine).

---

If we want to access the database from another container within the same network, we can reference the container by its name.